# Is this a duplicate of either of these questions?

Tags: discussion

I noticed [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/290050/what-did-the-new-version-of-skyrim-improve) get asked and marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/289683/are-there-any-differences-between-skyrim-skyrim-special-edition), but they really aren't asking the same thing.

While I agree with the fact that the ambiguous title makes it *seem* like an obvious duplicate, the first question is really asking what the 32- to 64-bit conversion of the remastered edition means for the game itself. Because of this, I disagree with the VTCs based on duplication of the second question.

*However*, the question of what 32- to 64-bit conversion means for a game *has* been asked before, but **for a different game**.

Namely, [this question about Transistor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/169169/what-is-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-launchers-of-transistor)

Would this question count as a duplicate of the Transistor question since both are asking the same core question or would it be valid since it is about a different game?

Answer (score 3):

A 32-bit to 64-bit conversion type-question is pretty much going to give the same answer, regardless of the game.  I think the [Skyrim question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/290050/what-improvements-exist-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-skyrim) is a duplicate of the transistor question.

Can a question about game X be a duplicate of a question about game Y?  Sure, why not?  Otherwise, do we support the same generic question for every game ever released?

Comment: Well sometimes generic questions do have different answers for different games, but I felt that a question like this would not.

Answer (score 3):

I was the one who initially voted to close the question. At the time, the question sounded like it was asking for the differences between Skyrim and Skyrim SE, but now with the edits that have been made, it is much more clear that the asker was specifically curious about how the new 64-bit architecture affects the gameplay experience. In that regard, I now agree with you, it is not a duplicate of the "differences between Skyrim and Skyrim SE" question.

However, I also don't think it is a duplicate of the Transistor question. Just as the Skyrim question is asking about how a 64-bit architecture affects Skyrim gameplay, the Transistor question is asking the same thing *but specific to Transistor gameplay*. The answer happens to be written in such a way that it answers both questions, but that does not mean the questions themselves are duplicates. They are technically asking about two different (but very similar) topics.

What I think might be useful is a canonical "32-bit vs. 64-bit version differences" question that can be applied to any game. Then, if necessary, questions can be asked for specific games if there is a *significant departure* from the canonical answer as far as gameplay differences (which in this case probably won't apply in most cases).

Comment: The problem with a generic 32-bit vs 64-bit version differences type question is that it will look like it will belong to another stack site.  Any game pretty much means any program/application too.